# Limits of cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions

I want to know if there is a formal proof of the statement that, given a cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)$, the limits $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} F_X(x) = 1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} F_X(x) = 0$ hold.

I have tried using the facts that, in every probability space, $P(\emptyset)=0$ and $P(\Omega)=1$. But I haven't figured out a proof yet.

Thanks to anyone.

Comment: How someone would answer this entirely depends on what you believe $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ means? Do you view it as a Lebsegue integral or a limit of Riemann integrals or something else?

Comment: For this you actually need "continuity of probability."  One way to state continuity of probability is this: For any sequence of events $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[\cup_{i=1}^n A_i] =P[\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i]$. Can you use this fact to prove what you want? (*Note: "Continuity of probability" follows from the axioms of probability, in particular the axiom about countable unions of disjoint events).

Comment: Thanks Michael, with that I can finish my proof. Could you please explain how that proposition follows from the axioms of probability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. Let $X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. Also, let $A_x = \{ \omega \in \Omega \colon X(\omega) \leq x \}$.

(In words, $A_x$ is just the set of outcomes such that our random variable $X$ takes a value of at most $x$. Also note that $A_x \in \mathcal{F}$ by the definition of a random variable.)

The distribution function of $X$ is the function $F_X \colon \mathbb{R} \to [0, 1]$ where $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x) = P(A_x)$.

Now that we've made our definitions, let's get down to business.

*Claim:* $\lim_{x \to \infty} F_X(x) = 1.$

*Proof:* Let $(x_n)$ be a monotonic sequence of real numbers converging to $\infty$. This means that $A_{x_n} \subseteq A_{x_{n + 1}}$ for all $n$. (Informally, the set of outcomes $\omega \in \Omega$ such that the random variable $X$ takes on a value of no more than $x_n$ can't be any larger than the set of outcomes $\omega$ such that $X$ takes on a value no more than $x_{n + 1}$, since $x_n \leq x_{n + 1}$ for all $n$.)

We therefore have a sequence of sets $A_{x_1} \subseteq A_{x_2} \subseteq A_{x_3} \subseteq \dots$, and it's important to note that $\cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{x_n} = \Omega$. (Why? Because the infinite union is all the $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $X(\omega) < \infty$, which is all of $\Omega$.)

I now need to call on the result that given a sequence of sets $(A_n)$ where $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq A_3 \subset \dots$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n) = P(\cup_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_i).$

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} F_X(x) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} F_X(x_n)\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_{x_n})\\
&= P \big( \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{x_n} \big)\\
&= P(\Omega)\\
&= 1.\square
\end{align*}

The proof that $\lim_{x \to -\infty}F_X(x) = 0$ is pretty similar.

Comment: Why is true the equality of the limit of the probabilities and the probability of the union set?

Comment: You define a new sequence of events $(B_n)$ where the elements are disjoint, but still "add up" through union to any $A_n$. (Imagine concentric circles where each $B_i$ is just the next ring.) Thus $\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_i = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} B_i$. Disjointness allows us to use the additivity property of a measure: $A_n = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n B_i \Rightarrow P  (A_n)  = P \big( \bigcup_{i = 1}^n B_i \big) = \sum_{i = 1}^n P(B_i)$. Let $n \to \infty$, use additivity property to change back to the probability of the union, use the equality given above, and you're done.